# nodejs+Q promises: no Reference Exception in the fulfillment handle

Tags: node.js, promise, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to nodejs, trying to write first larger project. Unfortunately I'm stuck with nodejs exits with no error when I made a mistake inside Q fullfilment handle.

Example:

```
var Q = require('q');
    function test1() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return(deferred.promise);
}

console.log("Start");
test1() 
.then (function(ret) {
    imnotexisting;   //this should be shown as Reference Exception
    console.log("OK");
}, function(err) {
    console.log("FAIL");
});
console.log("Stop");
```

'

The output will be:

```
Start
Stop
```

with no syntax/reference or any other error because of "imnotexisting" part.
Same error outside of fullfilment handle throws erorr as it should.

I'm using nodejs 4.4.4 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Same applies for nodejs 6.1.0

Comment: Any help or comment? This problem makes all my typos critical - as my project is quite complicated now - with many aync paths and long loops - some of execution paths inside app fails with no error message. Tracking them takes ages...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found this:

```
One sometimes-unintuive aspect of promises is that if you throw an exception in the fulfillment handler, it will not be caught by the error handler.
(...)
To see why this is, consider the parallel between promises and try/catch. We are try-ing to execute foo(): the error handler represents a catch for foo(), while the fulfillment handler represents code that happens after the try/catch block. That code then needs its own try/catch block.
```

We need to add .fail section as follows:

```
    var Q = require('q');
    function test1() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return(deferred.promise);
}

console.log("Start");
test1() 
.then (function(ret) {
    imnotexisting;
    console.log("OK");
}, function(err) {
    console.log("FAIL");
})
.fail (function(err) {
    console.log("Error: "+err);
});
console.log("Stop");
```

And the result is:
Start
Stop
Error: ReferenceError: imnotexisting is not defined